# Applying animation when removing a class from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code which applies `.upper` class to #top-btn and it appears at the bottom when the user scrolls down by a certain amount and removes it when they scroll back up. It animates #top-btn from the bottom of the page.

However when the class is removed while scrolling up, I want it to animate back down. The way I have it it just blinks away (because the class upper is just removed).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // adjust this number to select when your button appears on scroll-down
    var offset = 300,
    scroll_top_duration = 3000,

    // bind with the button link
    $animation = $('#top-btn');

    // apply animation
 $(window).scroll(function(){
     ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass('upper') :
     $animation.removeClass('upper');
 });
  });
```

```css
    body,html{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    }
    body{
    background-color:green;
    height:4000px;
    }
    #top-btn {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 999;
     padding: 0; margin: 0;
     bottom: -100px; right: 0;
    }

    #top-btn.upper { 
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
    }

    #top-btn-BG {
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 950;
     border-width: 0 0 100px 100px;
     border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
     border-style: solid;
     right: 0; bottom: 0;
     width: 0; height: 0;
     -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="top-btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: could you add your html too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing `.upper` you should add a class `.lower` which will have `bottom:-30px;`. If you don't know height of the button then you can set it from jquery.

Then your jquery will become like this:

```
( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? 
$animation.addClass('upper').removeClass("lower"):
$animation.addClass('lower').removeClass("upper");
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// adjust this number to select when your button appears on scroll-down
var offset = 300,
scroll_top_duration = 3000,

// bind with the button link
$animation = $('#top-btn');

// apply animation
$(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ?       $animation.addClass('upper').removeClass("lower"):
    $animation.addClass('lower').removeClass("upper");
    });
});
```

```css
body,html{
width:100%;
position:relative;
height:100%;
}
body{
background-color:green;
height:4000px;
}
#top-btn {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 padding: 0; margin: 0;
 bottom: -100px; right: 0;
}

#top-btn.upper { 
 bottom: 0;
 -webkit-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
 -moz-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
 -ms-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
 -o-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
 transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
}
#top-btn.lower { 
 bottom:-30px;
 -webkit-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
 -moz-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
 -ms-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
 -o-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
 transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
}

#top-btn-BG {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 950;
 border-width: 0 0 100px 100px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 right: 0; bottom: 0;
 width: 0; height: 0;
 -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="top-btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function in conditional operator for removing the class and scroll the page down. something like this:

```
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass('upper') :
    scrollDown();

    function scrollDown(){
       $('#top-btn').removeClass('upper');
       //here goes the code to scroll down//;
    }
```